# gdb can't insert a breakpoint when attach to a process

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to attach `gdb` to a program started by `socat` like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5678,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:./test
```

In another terminal,

```
sudo gdb 
attach `pidof socat`
br *0x080487D4
```

when execute `continue` command in gdb, it shows error like this:

```
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x80487d4

Command aborted.
```

0x080487D4 is in `.text` of `test` program. The `follow-fork-mode` of gdb is `child`, I have searched online but still can't solve it.

I debugged program successfully like this way a month ago, and don't know why it doesn't work now. But it's ok if debug the program directly using gdb like this:

```
gdb -q ./test
```

However, the way above doesn't meet my needs.

Through debugging, I think `gdb` expects that address is a valid address in the `socat` rather then `test` program. So how can I set breakpoints in `test` program? Without breakpoints in `test` program, it will run directly to the end when execute `continue` command. Setting breakpoints in `socat` program is useless.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you determining that that address is the correct address?  I don't see anything that you are doing to determine where `socat` has been mapped in memory.  Are you compiling as PIE code?

Comment: Why do you think you need sudo?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, Thanks your reply.  The address is obtained from Ida pro when decompile `test` program, not related to `socat`. When a process forks with socat, gdb will follow the child process `test`, so I set a breakpoint on that address.  Should I set a breakpoint in `socat` rather then `test` program?

Comment: @sigjuice. Sometimes it would fail to attach to the process without `sudo`.  Even without `sudo`, the problem still exists.

Comment: Either you need sudo all the time or you do not at all.   Using sudo unnecessarily is likely to cause other problems.

Comment: @sigjuice I tried both using sudo and not just now. The problem still exists. I really don't know how to deal with it. Maybe try to test with another computer. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: When you say _it worked a month ago_, was it the same `test` executable and the same address `0x080487D4`?

Comment: The executable is the same, but the address is slighly different. Any other debug method recommend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138398/discussion-between-sigjuice-and-cq674350529).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out how to set breakpoints in `test` program.

When start `test` program using `socat`, it won't fork a `test` process until a socket connection comes. So trying to set breakpoints directly in `test` program fails.

I use a tool(for my purpose, choose `pwntools`) to connect to it and suspend it ,then use `gdb` to attach to the forked `test` process. Next, I can debug normally.

Any better ideas? Thanks in advance.